# XCode 7 How to pin to superview and not toplayout guide

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the solution from this post. [Autolayout: Add constraint to superview and not Top Layout Guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766210/autolayout-add-constraint-to-superview-and-not-top-layout-guide)

But in xcode 7, this option is no longer available. Is it moved somewhere? Or is there another way to pin to superview bypassing the toplayoutguide? I found the toplayoutguide behaving differently for ios7,8,9. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that they have removed the menu option, but there is an arrow next to the place where you put your top/bottom/trailing/leading margins that will still give you that option.

Here are screenshots for the top and bottom layout guides. For some reason, I can't get the top layout guide to show up, but the bottom one is still there.
[image]
[image]