# How to avoid the 20 margin, when I set the top constraint to 0 in storyBoard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

How to avoid the 20 margin, when I set the constraint to 0?

You can see the below image, which have 20 more margin here, how to avoid that?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: click on the little arrow.... select the option that doesn't say top layout constraint or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Override this method to hide status bar in your UIViewController

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

In Storyboard, set `Status Bar: None` in the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution** :

Its solve your problem through constrains

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438583/3901620

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the launch image upper over than the status bar, then set the constraints.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>