# There is something block in my status bar, how to solve this

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface, statusbar

[image: xcode tool preview]

[image: iphone screenshot]

I have used to set something on statusbar position and I removed it. But now, I want to set the statusbar into clearcolor. And there was a view appeared. I checked the code already, there is nothing about the statusbar in my code. How to remove this view?

```
  - [2] : <UIView: 0x1014ecaf0; frame = (0 0; 414 20); tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0x17442ddc0>>
```

I printed the view's subviews, I don't know who create this view. And this view make the problem.

Comment: I can't able to identify ur issue... can u elaborate ur question and ur image is not clear to understand the issues

Comment: <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
 <false/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/>.   u checked these properties

Comment: I checked your keys in my project.I didn't set UIStatusBarHidden in my project.And "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" in my plist was NO already.

Comment: ok .... u want to set ur status bar colour custom colour..? ...now ...?

Comment: And i don't know who creat a view on the status bar position.It cover the background color. I swear i did't creat a view in this controller.

Comment: is this presentviewcontroller ?

Comment: add this line : if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: Did I understand right, that you are trying to paint your status bar the same color as the view under it?

Comment: statusbar should be clearcolor in default setting.i don't know why there auto-create a view under the status bar. And this small view cover the view background color.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your top view in Interface Builder is arranged to the `Top Layout Guide`. If you want it to be somewhat overlapped by the `Status Bar`, so the `Status Bar` lie on it and use its color as backroung, you need set your top constaint to be arranged with the `superview`, not the the `Top Layout Guide`.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766210/autolayout-add-constraint-to-superview-and-not-top-layout-guide) answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think i find the wrong in my code.I'm so sorry.I used my teammate's tool class,he create a view cover the status bar to solve his problem.In some special condition that view didn't exist.So i find it for a long time.Sorry about that.

But i still learn a lot.Thank all you guys.