# Bottom Margin in iPhone X using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x

Ok I have this case,

There is this screen I designed for iphone 8

[image]

As you can see here there is 8px green view that I pinned to the bottom of the superview by making a constrain of 0px between this view and top of bottom layout guide. and it works fine on all phone EXCEPT for the new iPhone X where this happens:

[image]

and thats not my intended behaviour. I want to to be as the other iPhones, pinned to the bottom with 0 margin.

Is there is a solution for that using the storyboard? Please post solutions using storyboard only. I know that I can do it programmatically. this should be easy on storyboard I guess.

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

1- Select your view in storyboard

￼[image: ￼]

2- Double click on bottom space constraint and select **Superview** for first item
[image]

3- Set constant value to 0

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this

[image]

By Setting AutoResizing like this in storyboard

[image]

With AutoLayouts

[image]

Comment: I want to know whether it is achievable through autolayout ? As @Mostafa MohamedRaafat asked

Comment: @ShivamTripathi Thank you :) but I want to make it using Autolayout

Answer (score 3):

In storyboard select "View as: iPhone X" and pin the desired view to superview, not Bottom Layout Guide or Safe Area (in my example it's a full screen image view, your view would be pinned only to bottom):

[image]

Alternatively, if you are not in iPhone X view, you can pin bottom edge to superview by dragging with ctrl key and then when selecting from the list, press option key - more details in this answer: [Autolayout: Add constraint to superview and not Top Layout Guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766210/autolayout-add-constraint-to-superview-and-not-top-layout-guide/37438583#37438583)